# Why does PHP in "interactive shell" mode only run this script once?

Tags: php, shell, command-line, terminal

The first time I paste this little test `for` loop in PHP interactive shell mode (`php -a` from the command line), it runs perfectly.

```
for($weekday == 0;  $weekday<7; $weekday++) { echo $weekday; }
```

Then I try pasting it and running it again a few times, it never returns any output. Why does it work the first time and do nothing after that?

Output:

[image]

And `php -v` returns `PHP 7.1.1 (cli) (built: Jan 23 2017 15:09:57) ( NTS )`

**UPDATE:** yes, I am stupid and used the comparison operator instead of the assignment operator. Dur. :-) But still, my original question is valid: WITH the comparison operator (as seen above), even though it is not exactly doing what I want it to do, *why does it only execute once?*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the `==` to `=` to reset `$weekday` back to `0` each time.

```
for($weekday = 0;  $weekday<7; $weekday++) { echo $weekday; }
```

Otherwise, the second time it runs `$weekday` is already `7` and the loop condition fails immediately.